# measurable sets.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let ${f_n}$ be sequence of measurable real-valued functions on the measurable space $(\Omega, \Sigma)$. Prove that the following set is measurable:
The set P comprising all $\omega\in\Omega$ such that $f_n(\omega)$ converges to an irrational number.

- If it's rational instead of irrational number, then it's certainly countable, and then we can rewrite the statement as either union or intersections of countable index.
- If it's real, which is not countable, but $\mathbb{ R}$ is complete so cauchy converges. Then we can use the property of cauchy to prove countable for such a set.

However, I don't know what to do with a irrational number...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a fact (or an exercise if you don't know the fact) that the set of all $\omega$ for which the sequence $f_n(\omega)$ converges is measurable. You said you can show the set of all $\omega$ for which $f_n(\omega)$ converges to a rational number is measurable. So, the set of $\omega$ for which $f_n(\omega)$ converges to an irrational number is just the set difference of those two measurable sets, which is of course measurable.

Comment: omg right... Thank you!